# Multidimensional array to grid style textbox with input box, including a sum of array and retrieve a specific day

Tags: arrays, vb.net, multidimensional-array, inputbox

So, I can't figure out how to get the user to be able to retrieve the number of products completed for any day of any week of the month.

After the execution of the 4 weeks are done, the user is prompted to enter the week and the day of the week by InputBox’s that they wish to retrieve information for. Assume  that  the  users  enter  the  day  of  the  week  in  string  format,  such  as “Monday” or “Tuesday” etc

There would have to be another input box, and that's the thing, I can't figure out how to code it so that the user can chose what day and week by inputting it into the inputbox. Would you have to make 2 input boxes just to retrieve that day and week?

```
toys(day, 0) = InputBox("Enter what day") 
toys(0, week) = InputBox("Enter what week")
```

Also, I need to get the full sum of the whole array, when you look at the picture, it has the total of 210 and I can't figure out how to get the full sum.

This is the code for the output so far.

```
Private Sub btnExecute_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExecute.Click

    Dim toys(4, 3) As String
    For week As Integer = 0 To 3
        For day As Integer = 0 To 4
            toys(day, week) = InputBox("Please enter value for Day " & CStr(day + 1) & " in week " & CStr(week + 1) & ".", "Enter Value", (value + 1))
        Next day
    Next week

    txtOutput.Text &= vbTab + "Mon" + vbTab + "Tue" + vbTab + "Wed" + vbTab + "Thur" + vbTab + "Fri" + vbCrLf

    For week As Integer = 0 To 3
        txtOutput.Text &= "Week " + (week + 1).ToString + " "
        For day As Integer = 0 To 4
            txtOutput.Text += vbTab + toys(day, week)
            For i = 0 To 10 - toys(day, week).Length
                txtOutput.Text += " "
            Next
            If day = 4 Then
                txtOutput.Text &= vbCrLf

            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Here is the expected output.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub btnExecute_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExecute.Click
    Dim toys(4, 3) As String
    For week As Integer = 0 To 3
        For day As Integer = 0 To 4
            toys(day, week) = "..."
        Next day
    Next week
    txtOutput.Text &= "                   Mon" + vbTab + "Tue" + vbTab + "Wed" + vbTab + "Thu" + vbTab + "Fri" + vbCrLf
    For week As Integer = 0 To 3
        txtOutput.Text &= "Week " + (week + 1).ToString + "      "
        For day As Integer = 0 To 4
            txtOutput.Text += toys(day, week)
            For i = 0 To 10 - toys(day, week).Length
                txtOutput.Text += " "
            Next
            If day = 4 Then
                txtOutput.Text &= vbCrLf
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

You may have to change number of spaces.

Comment: I have inserted the output, it's back in the question. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Very helpful. I changed a couple of little things to make it work for me. 

`txtOutput.Text &= vbTab + "Mon" + vbTab + "Tue" + vbTab + "Wed" + vbTab + "Thur" + vbTab + "Fri" + vbCrLf.`

It needed the vbtab instead of the spaces and also.

`For day As Integer = 0 To 4
                txtOutput.Text += vbTab + toys(day, week)`

It needed a vbtab to spread the text out. :)